# Учесть в событии CheckBox_CheckedChanged какая кнопка нажата в последний раз

Tags: c#

Есть Чекбокс, и событие его изменения.

Есть необходимость внутри выполнять проверку, какая кнопка в последней раз нажата( ну или подсвечена видимо) И в зависимости от это сортируются данные.

```
        private void Form1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
    }
```

Тогда как мне clickedButton отправить в событие чекбокса? о_О

Comment: Создайте поле _lastClickedButton и в обработчиках кнопок записывайте туда название нажатой кнопки. Не совсем понятен принцип, зачем это Вам.

Comment: Блин так же все  просто. Спасибо.
У меня кнопки используются вместо вкладок. Соответственно сортировку списка  надо выполнять с учетом того, в какой категории находится пользователь.

Чекбоксы как раз выполняют сортировку, отсюда и потребность передавать туда нажатую кнопку.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону RadioButton, думаю в вашем случае с ними будет проще, их тоже можно показывать в виде кнопок